# How to request a start for startUpdatingLocation?

Tags: swift, mapkit, locationmanager

I'm starting a location manager as i open the view with this code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    var userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation

    userLatitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    userLongitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    if (userLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 80) {

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    } else {

        addMapRegionAndAnnotation()

    }

}
```

So this means the locationManager does Stop if the location is detected in a 80m radius.
Now i want to start this locationManager again if i press my updateLocation button:

```
@IBAction func updatePostMapView(sender: AnyObject) {

    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Then the app shuold update the user location till the radius is smaller then 80m again...
But as you may expect, this isn't working because i can't call the manager.startUpdatingLocation() from outside of the locationManager.

Has anyone a solution?

Comment: You need to save a reference to your `CLLocationManager` in a property when you create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call startUpdatingLocation() or stopUpdatingLocation() from inside of any method. First You must create location manager within your class,

```
class
```

`let locationManager = CLLocationManager()`

```
func initializeLocationManager()
{

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters


}
func anyMethod()
{
   locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```